# Double Integral Simplification

Tags: integration

I came across the equality 
$$\int_a^x\int_a^tf(s)dsdt=\int_{a}^xf(s)(x-s)ds,$$
in a text that claims this is a simple exercise using partial integration, but I just don't see it. When I perform partial integration on either side, I end up with terms involving $f'$ which only complicates it further. How can I prove this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically change the order of integration. The region for which you are integrating over is "upper triangle" (with $t$ axis being vertical) bounded by curves $t=x,s=a,s=t$.

So if you change the order of integration,

$$
\int_a^x \int_a^t f(s)\,ds\,dt=\int_a^x \int_s^x f(s)\,dt\,ds=\int_a^x f(s)(x-s)\,ds
$$

originally you integgrate horizontally first then vertically, but you change order of integration by integrating vertical strips first.